# How can I get an WCF service to return an XML document instead of object array

Tags: wcf

I have a simple operation contract like:

```
[OperationContract]
XmlDocument GetDepartmentTree2(string node, string id);
```

On the client side I want to use the XmlDocument, but WCF returns an object array.

This is how it works (besides it is ugly):

```
 [OperationContract, XmlSerializerFormat]
 XmlDocument GetDepartmentTree2(string node, string id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `XElement` instead of `XmlDocument`. It works just fine with the default data contract serializer, and doesn't require decorating with any extra attributes.